# Server-sent-events platforms that can watch the filesystem in real time for updates?

Tags: php, node.js, json, server-sent-events

I'm trying to figure out what platforms can do server-sent-events that also have the ability to hook into the filesystem to watch the source data file (in this case json) and push out an event in real time upon that file being updated.

I've used SSE a bit previously and I'm still a bit new to it but have produced some functional code. But so far I've only done it via PHP (hosted on Nginx) which as far as I know doesn't have a function to monitor the FS for realtime updates. Here's an example what I've done previously. Very simplistic but it works. But it does take at least a few seconds or so for new updates to push through.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$data = file_get_contents("data.json");

echo 'data: ' . $data . "\n\n";

ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Earlier today I decided to try and mangle my way through a proof of concept nodejs script for this with some help from Copilot to give me a few function pointers. NodeJS was chosen because it was the first system that came up when searching for what platforms have the ability to hook the filesystem directly. In testing, it is fantastic with an instantaneous response to the client web page. But my god does it feel very rube-goldberg-y having to basically build a web server in the code from the ground up. I understand the need and flexibility, it just makes my brain hurt a bit. lol. I'm more used to PHP where the web server is already there and ready to go (short of some CLI only work of course).

So I'm curious if maybe there are any other solutions out there for this combination of tasks? To give a TL;DR: Looking to do SSE but the source json file on the host machine is hooked in the filesystem to watch for updates and push them out to the client in real time.

Comment: This is a well-crafted question, but it is going to get closed because it asking for recommendations.  If you re-phrased it to: "How do I write an SSE server to monitor the file system in the fewest number of lines (any language)?" it would probably be fine. Personally I'd do this in Node+express, though it might end up Linux-specific, as I'm not sure how to monitor the filesystem in a cross-platform way.